# realloc an array of pointers is doing nothing

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, realloc

I have an array of strings, and I would like to extand it when it no longer has NULL pointers (meaning the array is full).
I have tried realloc with no success, I think i'm not thinking right pointer-wise.

Here is my code:

```
int storage; //global, outside of main
int i, key;
char **people;
char **phones;

printf("Please enter a storage cacpity:\n");
scanf("%d",&storage);
printf("\n");

people=malloc(storage*sizeof(char *));
phones=malloc(storage*sizeof(char *));

for (i=0; i<storage; i++) {
    people[i] = NULL;
    phones[i] = NULL;
}

void AddNewContact(char * people[], char * phones[]) {
    char name[100];
    char phone[12];
    int i, listfull = 0;

    printf("Enter a contact name:\n");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    printf("Enter a phone number:\n");
    scanf("%s",&phone);

    for (i=0; i<storage; i++) {
        if (people[i]==NULL) {
            people[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(name));
            phones[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(phone));
            strcpy(people[i],name);
            strcpy(phones[i],phone);
            break;
        }
        listfull = 1;
    }

    if (listfull == 1) {
        storage++;
        people = realloc(&people,(storage)*sizeof(char *));
        phones = realloc(&phones,(storage)*sizeof(char *));
        people[storage-1] = NULL;
        phones[storage-1] = NULL;
        strcpy(people[storage-1],name);
        printf("\nData Base extanded to %d",storage);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

void PrintAll(char * people[], char * phones[]) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<storage; i++) {
        if (NULL != people[i]) {
            printf("Name: %s, ",people[i]);
            printf("Number: %s\n",phones[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, I'm stuck on it for a few hours and having no luck sovling this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "no success"?  What are you doing to see whether it succeeded or not?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, I'm adding users, when the capcity is maxed out (no NULLs) I want to extand it by one.

Comment: @NirTzezana: And what exactly is the problem that you're having?

Comment: `people` and `&people` are not the same.

Comment: @jwodder the realloc isn't working, the array isn't increasing by one.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, you should probably change your `strcpy(people[i], name);` and `strcpy(phones[i], phone);` to `strncpy(people[i], name);` and `strncpy(phones[i], phone);`. This won't solve your problem, but it will NULL terminate the string.

Comment: @NirTzezana: How can you tell?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I know they're not the same, &people is the memory address of the main pointer.

Comment: @jwodder Sorry, I updated the code, I'm using PrintAll after realloc but the program terminates.

Comment: If the string you input into phone is `"123-456-7890"` then you will overflow `char phone[12]`.

Comment: Do you have statements outside of any function? Like the for loop or the malloc calls at the beginning of your code.

Comment: Thumb rule: You cannot realloc a pointer which is not returned by mallloc and family. Q: is `&people` in that category?

Comment: Oh and as a second suggestion, please **NEVER** do this: `people = realloc(&people,(storage)*sizeof(char *));`. If the realloc fails, NULL is returned which means `people` becomes a NULL pointer. Thus you lose the pointer to that block of memory. You should assign the return value of realloc to a separate variable and `if ( NULL != returnedReallocAddress )  people = returnedReallocAddress;`

Comment: @PhilippMurry Everything needed for those function is in the code up there, you can view the full code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/pCjUwsdA

Comment: @Elvisjames, he could also just use `peoples = calloc(storage, sizeof(char *));`. Calloc returns a pointer to a block of memory initialized/filled with 0's. Thus you only call calloc instead of calling both malloc and memset.

Comment: @SpencerDoak Thanks for the useful tips, i'll be sure to use them from now on... sadly I still can't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: @iharob yes, if the loop doesn't break that means the array has no NULLs, thus needs another cell.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&name);` will be a problem if the name has a space in it like "Nir Tzezana".  Suggest posting sample input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 4 important mistakes, first you are passing the address of the array to `scanf()` that's wrong, you should change

```
scanf("%s", &name);
```

to

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

as well as `scanf("%s",&phone);`, I also should recommend to use length specifiers for `scanf` to prvent buffer overflow, for example

```
scanf("%99s", name);
```

i.e. the length of the `name` array -1, for the `'\0'` terminator.

Second, your `realloc` call is also wrong, you should pass the pointer instead of it's address, instead of this

```
people = realloc(&people,(storage)*sizeof(char *));
```

you should do this

```
people = realloc(people, storage * sizeof(char *));
```

but even this is not 100% right, because in case `realloc` fails, you will overwrite the pointer, and then you wont have a chance to clean up memory, so you should actually do something like

```
void *pointer;
pointer = realloc(people, storage * sizeof(char *));
if (pointer == NULL)
    free_people_andCleanUpOtherResourcesAndExitFromThisFunction();
people = pointer;
```

the same goes for `phones`.

Third you should always allocate space for one extra character, the terminating `'\0'`, this

```
people[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(name));
```

should read

```
people[i] = malloc(1 + strlen(name));
```

notice that I removed the cast which is not necessary.

Fourth you break out from the loop in the first iteration leaving `listfull == 1`, even when there is list is not full yet.

```
for (i=0; i<storage; i++) {
    if (people[i]==NULL) {
        people[i] = malloc(1 + strlen(name));
        phones[i] = malloc(1 + strlen(phone));
        strcpy(people[i],name);
        strcpy(phones[i],phone);
        break;
    }
    listfull = 1;
}
```

I'd recommend this outside of the loop

```
listfull = (i == storage);
```

**Note**: it doesn't matter how unlikely a function will fail, if it theoretically would fail, you should always check for it's failure, that will save you hours of debugging to find a very stupid mistake, you didn't check for the possible failure.

Comment: Thanks, the program still crashes when trying to extand the array with realloc.

Comment: There is a third important mistake: In C, strings are an array of characters terminated by a NUL character `'\0'`. The length returned by `strlen` does **not** include the NUL character. So all of the buffers that the OP uses are too small by 1 character.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks, I updated this to strlen(name)+1)

Comment: @user3386109 abslutely right, I didn't notice that.

Comment: @iharob first of all - thanks for the help! second - sadly, the program still crashes, I've made all the changes you have suggested.

Comment: @NirTzezana check the **Note**, you should check the return value from `malloc`.

Comment: @iharob I've seen it, I'm new to C and not skilled with it, yet.
I have checked the value returned from malloc but i'm also not so skilled in debugging, I'll keep trying.

Comment: Sure, this is the code after all changes suggested by you: http://pastebin.com/45grLUrs, I haven't touched the scanf.

Comment: @NirTzezana if you want you can contact me iharob@gmail.com

Comment: @iharob, if the break out from the loop was on the *second* or greater iteration that would leave `listfull == 1`.

Comment: In fact you shouldn't cast a return from `malloc()` cause it can "hide" bugs in your code.

Answer (score 4):

You have

```
listfull = 1;
```

inside your `(for i ...)` loop, it should be outside the loop, like this

```
if (i == storage)           // if loop completed
    listfull = 1;
```

Next, your partial program comments that some variables are declared globally, yet they are followed by executable code statements which *must* be within a function, so are the "global" variables actually, local?

Comment: Weather, I believe the OP has pasted pieces of the actual code rather than including all of the actual code. I would guess the variables which are commented as "global" are likely defined globally and the code following them is likely within some function which he did not include the declaration for. That said, the code is a tad confusing because of that.

Comment: Are you talking about storage, it needs to be global beacuse its being used in many functions. You can see the full code here: http://pastebin.com/45grLUrs

Comment: @SpencerDoak I thought it would be better to paste parts of the code instead the whole code, beacuse its shorter and more focused on the part that isn't working.

Comment: @NirTzezana if `people` and `phones` are global why did you need to pass them to `AddNewContact()`?

Comment: @WeatherVane they are not global, only storage is global.

Comment: @NirTzezana, yes only showing the relevant pieces of code is usually preferred on SO, but might I recommend for future questions that you include the function declarations (e.g. `returnType functName(params) { ... }`). This allows readers to notice separations between functions and global variables. That said, thank you for being conservative and not throwing all of your code into the question. It can be quite overwhelming to help someone who posts every line of their project.